# How to check if a cookie is expired

Tags: http, go, cookies, go-gin

How do I check if a cookie I get through a GET request is expired or not?
I tried:

```
cookie, err := c.Request.Cookie("session")
if err == nil && time.Now().Before(cookie.Expires) {
    log.Printf("COOKIE IS STILL GOOD. YUM!\n")
    return
}
```

But when I debug I see the expiration date is incorrect:

```
2019/05/15 01:23:46 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

The date is today, rather than 2051 like I set it to be, and nothing else makes sense. What is happening?

Comment: `2019/05/15 01:23:46` is a prefix added by the log package.  The value of the Expires field is `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, the zero value for time.Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because clients send names and values only in a [Cookie header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.2), the Name and Value fields are the only fields set in this context. The [Expires](https://godoc.org/net/http#Cookie.Expires) field has the time.Time [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) as the log output indicates.

The application must do something outside of the cookie protocol to determine if the cookie is still valid.

Comment: Oh well. That kinda sucks. Thing is, while using `http.Request.Cookie()` it seemed to work. Did it just look like it's working? Or is it something about GinGonic? And how could I solve it in a decent way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with GinGonic.  Clients do not send the expiration time. Look for a "secure cookie" package. Most of these packages include an expiration time in the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie has expired it will not be in the `document.cookie` value. Since that value is a string, you can search it for the key (name) of your cookie using `indexOf()`. If it isn't there, it either expired or was never set.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('key-name')===-1){
   //value was not found, must be expire
}else{
   //not expired
}
```